# data prediction by regression or better ways

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, optimization, nonlinear-regression, regression-coefficients

I am working on data prediction. Given data of a random variable $X$ and $Y$, find out how to predict $Y$ from $X$. I know how to do it by linear regression, $\hat{Y} = kX + b$.

But, here, $X$ is always non-negative and $Y$ is required to be non-negative. Sometimes, $b$ is not non-negative so that $y < 0$. How to assure that $b > 0$ and also minimize the prediction error?

Are there other better ways (not regression) to do the prediction ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fit a model with a non-negative fit is to fit a model that can't go negative.

If, for example, you want the fit to be always-positive and your data is always-positive,

i) you could take the log of the y, and fit a model to that, transforming back (but beware, while quantiles transform happily, means don't, so some care must be taken with this case)

ii) you could fit a generalized linear model, such as a gamma or inverse-Gaussian GLM (or with count data, perhaps a Poisson, binomial or negative binomial model), especially if the link function is suitably chosen

iii) you could fit a nonlinear least squares model which is designed to stay positive, for example by including exponential terms

iv) you could use any of a number of approaches for constraining parameters in such a way as to guarantee non-negativity for a given range of values. For example, many optimization routines offer the ability to fit with box-constraints.